# Next.js react-chatbot-kit default style is not working

Tags: javascript, next.js

```
import Chatbot from 'react-chatbot-kit'
import config from './config'
import ActionProvider from './actionProvider'
import MessageParser from './messageParser'

const ChatBotFlight = () => {
return (
 <div>
    <Chatbot
      config={config}
      actionProvider={ActionProvider}
      messageParser={MessageParser}
    />
</div>
)
}

export default ChatBotFlight
```

In my project it's look like this
[image]

But when I checked docs or tutorial videos if you add Chatbott component it comes with default styling which not available on my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt import the CSS.

In the [Docs](https://fredrikoseberg.github.io/react-chatbot-kit-docs/docs/getting-started) there is this Part:

```
import 'react-chatbot-kit/build/main.css'
```

Try this.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I missed it